Is there a "maximal" compact, totally disconnected Hausdorff space with a countable base of clopen subsets?
It is a well-established fact that the Cantor set $\mathcal C$ is the perfect, compact, totally disconnected Hausdorff space with a countable base of clopen subsets.
But, more broadly, is $\mathcal C$ a maximal compact, totally disconnected Hausdorff space with a countable base of clopen subsets, in the sense that every other such space is isomorphic to some closed subset of $\mathcal C$?
It  seems to me like this isn't the case, but I struggle with constructing an explicit counterexample. And, if not, is there such a maximal space?

Yes, it is well-known that a zero-dimensional Hausdorff space with a countable base can be embedded into $\mathcal C$, see Engelking, General topology 6.2.16.

BTW: maximal is a somewhat misleading name, since this usually refers to maximal topologies with respect to a certain property. The common name is universal (although this means embeddable, not necessarily closed, but here closed is implied by compactness).
